# Limit the scope of dependency in gradle

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I am using gradle 3.2.1. I have a framework that pulls up dependencies (newer version). But the problem is that my project already has these dependencies (old version) and I don't want to change their version. And the required framework cannot work without a new version. And my question is, can you restrict the built-in dependencies of the framework only for it? and use the same version for my application? is there such a possibility in gradle?
An example of how i exclude the loading of components, but i need to leave them only for this dependency:

```
compile(group: 'io.javalin', name: 'javalin', version: '4.1.1') {
        exclude group: 'org.eclipse.jetty'
        exclude group: 'org.eclipse.jetty.websocket'
    }
```

Comment: you need to read gradle variant-aware capabilities, but that only works from gradle 6, iirc.

Comment: @Eugene It's a pity, thanks for the answer !

Comment: you can have a look [here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/18655) where I faced kind of the same problem, if you want to dig deeper